# Can I put hardiebacker over green sheetrock in a shower?

Tags: drywall, shower, bathtub

I have a bathroom, already sheetrocked with the green moisture resistant sheetrock.

My tile guy told me I need to do hardiback for him to tile on, for the shower/bath's tiling on the wall.

Rather than ripping out the green sheetrock and redoing it in hardiback,
***my plan is to staple up a vapor barrier (just a 3-mil plastic dropcloth),
and then screw 1/4" hardiback board over the top of the green sheetrock.***

Can I reasonably do 1/4" hardiback over a vapor barrier over green sheetrock, for a tiled shower/bath?

Comment: You can do whatever you like. Your tile guy might not like your choice, though. 5 years down the line, you might not either. But if you are doing it to suit your tile guy, ask them. I know I'd kick anyone suggesting use of a 3 mil dropcloth as a vapor or moisture barrier offsite then and there. That's amateurish in the worst way.

Comment: Green board can be tiled, but if you want it to last better use the fibre-cement. There no point half-arseing the fibre cement, you may as well stay with the green board, but it seems that to do that you will need a different tiler.

Comment: @ecnerwal I am an amateur. =P What should I do instead of plastic dropcloth, under the concrete board?

Comment: @jasen My tiler will do whatever, hardieback was his strong suggestion. My question is, what should I do to make my bathroom last well long-term? Rip out the green sheetrock? Why should I not just do thin concrete board over the green? (the extra thickness will be easily hidden) And what would I put between the green and concrete-board? I want to do what's best here long-term, not what's easiest, short-term.

Comment: @jasen Basically, I'm asking how to not half-arse it, because left on my own, that's what I'd accidentally do. =P

Answer (score 4):

Glue and screw the cement board to the green-board.

Use 1 1/2" screws to anchor the panels to the studs.

Forget about the plastic. Seal the walls and the floor with a waterproofing and uncoupling membrane such as  [AquaDefense](https://thetoollocker.com/products/mapelastic-aquadefense-waterproofing-membrane?variant=31983762210916&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=CjwKCAjw8symBhAqEiwAaTA__NyroELlSZIMltQ8ZaVcS6EsIkT1IDhuB6dGEX3b8fVMs0DkR1p8pxoCgecQAvD_BwE) or [Red Guard](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/paint-and-supplies/patch-and-repair/spackling-compounds/1408434?x429=true&gclid=CjwKCAjw8symBhAqEiwAaTA__O0-qhjlPb__EXKVd2uxz-ujG-_cXOBYzB9--bOxpCcN1GjVmBNRGhoCBssQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

If your tile guy doesn't like that, you need a new tile guy.

Comment: Am I sealing under the hardiebacker, or am I sealing over the hardiebacker? The floor is concrete, do I still seal the floor?

Comment: you apply the water sealer to the hardiebacker, then tile over that.  Water sealer should be applied to the floor of the shower, if you do not have a PVC liner.

Comment: The shower is also a bathtub, so the "floor" of the shower is the bathtub (*the floor of the entire bathroom is concrete, on the ground floor of the house, but raised above outdoor ground level*) Do I still seal the concrete floor under the bathtub?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to seal the floor under the tub.  The order would be: hardi over green board, sealer over hardi, tile over the sealer.